# Oracle : returning different values in two columns

Tags: oracle

I have this query and would like to return only the differences in the 2 columns...

```
SELECT 
    C.id, C.START, D.start1
FROM 
    table1 C
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 D ON C.ID = D.ID AND C.CARD = D.CARD
```

Table:

```
 Id      Start     start1
  1      1/1/15    1/1/15
  2      1/2/15    1/2/15
  3      1/5/15    1/6/15
  4      1/9/15    1/9/16
```

I would like to see...

```
 Id      Start      Start1
 3      1/5/15      1/6/15
 4      1/9/15      1/9/16
```

I'm not sure where to start, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not necessary to join the table on if you aren't utilizing any of the fields in your query. @JaydipJ there may be a reason he is using the left join and he simplified his query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work: Wrap your query by an outer query and check condition**

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
    SELECT C.id, C.START, D.start1
    FROM table1 C
    LEFT JOIN table2 D ON C.ID = D.ID AND C.CARD = D.CARD
 ) q
WHERE q.START != q.start1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Select Id,Start,start1 from table where start !=start1
```